# Why doesn't static library show up as black in Xcode when built?

Tags: xcode, xcode8

If I build a static library in Xcode 8.3 either by `New Project... -> Library` or `New Target... -> Library` the build succeeds and the ".a" file is generated correctly, but the build product always shows as red, i.e. "file not found" in the Project Navigator.

I can confirm the file exists, as shown below. This happens regardless of whether I build for "Debug" or "Release".

Any way to fix this or is it an Xcode bug?

[image: Static library red in Project Navigator]

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a bug; if you build it and quit then re-open Xcode it should show up black.

Comment: Ah thanks, you are right.